# jQuery find width of each li element?

Tags: jquery

anyone know a way to find the width of each li within the ul?

I tried

```
var totalWidth;
jQuery("ul li").each(function() { totalWidth += jQuery(this).outerWidth(); });
```

But didn't work...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to initialize the variable first:

```
var totalWidth = 0;
```

...otherwise you're starting out effectively doing:

```
undefined += jQuery(this).outerWidth();
```

...which results in `NaN` for subsequent iterations:

```
NaN += jQuery(this).outerWidth();
```

Comment: thanks for that and the explanation...Also would you happen to know how to assign negative sign to the width I just found on a script like this: jQuery("someWidth").css("marginLeft", "-"+totalWidth); ? this doesn't work of course...

Comment: @Rick: You're welcome. To get a negative number, just use `-totalWidth` without the quotation marks, or change your loop to use `-=` instead of `+=`, which will calculate a negative number from the start.

Answer (score 0):

Initiate the variable as 0.  Your code seems like it should work